# What kind of method doesn't need a decorator or argument?

Tags: python

So I am aware of three different methods for classes: regular ones that act on instances,
class methods, and static methods. From tutorials I'm lead to believe that if your class function doesn't take an argument, it is a static method and you need the @staticmethod decorator. However, I wrote a function that is working perfectly for what I wanted, and it has no decorator or argument. Whats going on here?

see determiner()

```
class Parantheses():

    new_list = []

    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string

    def paran_sorter(self):
        i = 0
        for _ in range(len(self.string)):
            if self.string[i] == ')' or self.string[i] == '(' or self.string[i] == '[' or self.string[i] == ']' or self.string[i] == '{' or self.string[i] == '}':
                Parantheses.new_list.append(self.string[i])
            i += 1
        return Parantheses.new_list

    def determiner():
        n = 0
        for _ in Parantheses.new_list:
            while n < len(Parantheses.new_list):

                if Parantheses.new_list[n] == '(':
                    if Parantheses.new_list[n+1] == ')':
                        print(f"Valid Parantheses:, {Parantheses.new_list[n]}, {Parantheses.new_list[n+1]}")
                        n += 2
                    else:
                        print(f"Invalid Parantheses: {Parantheses.new_list[n]}, {Parantheses.new_list[n+1]}")
                        n += 1
                elif Parantheses.new_list[n] == '[':
                    if Parantheses.new_list[n+1] == ']':
                        print(f"Valid Parantheses:, {Parantheses.new_list[n]}, {Parantheses.new_list[n+1]}")
                        n += 2
                    else:
                        print(f"Invalid Parantheses: {Parantheses.new_list[n]}, {Parantheses.new_list[n+1]}")
                        n += 1
                elif Parantheses.new_list[n] == '{':
                    if Parantheses.new_list[n+1] == '}':
                        print(f"Valid Parantheses:, {Parantheses.new_list[n]}, {Parantheses.new_list[n+1]}")
                        n += 2
                    else:
                        print(f"Invalid Parantheses: {Parantheses.new_list[n]}, {Parantheses.new_list[n+1]}")
                        n += 1
                else:
                    if n < len(Parantheses.new_list):
                        print(f"Invalid Parentheses: {Parantheses.new_list[n]}, {Parantheses.new_list[n+1]}")
                        n +=1


sen_1 = Parantheses("[]")
sen_1.paran_sorter()
Parantheses.determiner()
```

Comment: *"if your class function doesn't take an argument, it is a static method"* — Not correct. If it doesn't want/need/take the ***`self`*** argument, i.e. the instance. Then it can be static.

Comment: The way you're calling `determiner` is no different from a regular function call. It indeed makes no difference here. You'd see a difference if you'd call it on an instance like `sen_1.determiner()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Foo:
    def bar(*args):
        print(args)
```

Take this simple example to see how a basic method behaves:

```
>>> Foo.bar()
()
```

When called like `Foo.bar()`, it's no different than a regular function. In fact, it *is* a regular function:

```
>>> type(Foo.bar)
<class 'function'>
```

However, when accessed on an instance:

```
>>> type(Foo().bar)
<class 'method'>

>>> Foo().bar()
(<__main__.Foo object at 0x10cb21d90>,)
```

It's now a special kind of function, a *method*, which will receive the object instance as its first argument.
<sub>(In earlier Python versions there were "bound" and "unbound" methods and such, but that is now obsolete.)</sub>

So, without any decorator, it depends on *how you call* the function. Calling it on the class won't pass anything, calling it on an instance will pass the instance object as the first parameter. This works with this example function which accepts an arbitrary number of positional `*args`, but of course fails if your function wants to be called a certain way:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        pass

    def baz():
        pass
```

```
>>> Foo.bar()
TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

>>> Foo().baz()
TypeError: baz() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

This is usually the correct and desired behaviour. A method that requires `self` can't be called on the class, and a method that doesn't accept `self`… should arguably not exist, at the very least not as plain undecorated method.

### Decorators

And this is where the various decorators come in:

#### `staticmethod`

The `staticmethod` decorator **always** suppresses the first implicit argument. A `staticmethod` will **never** be passed `self` and can hence be called either way:

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        pass
```

```
>>> Foo.bar()
>>> Foo().bar()  # look ma, no error!
```

The usefulness of such a function is debatable, as they're just regular functions in a class' namespace; arguably they should be detached from the class.

#### `classmethod`

The `classmethod` decorator always causes the *class* object to be passed as the first argument instead of the instance:

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        print(cls)
```

```
>>> Foo.bar()
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> Foo().bar()
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

You might ask why you need that as you could use a `staticmethod` and directly use `Foo` instead of `cls`, as they refer to the same object. This becomes interesting with inheritance:

```
class Child(Foo):
    pass
```

```
>>> Child.bar()
<class '__main__.Child'>
```